# Merge Azure Subscription with MSDN Subscription

Tags: azure, msdn

We have an Azure subscription (Pay-As-You-Go) on one email a1@rolsped.com (username) and a separate MSDN Visual Studio Enterprise subscription on another email address a2@rolsped.com (username).

The Azure subscription is for production (Pay-As-You-Go). What I found is that: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/credit-for-visual-studio-subscribers/

But this would create a complete new Azure subscription and it is stated that this is for **DEV/TEST** purposes only. I read between those lines that the preformance would not be as good as what we have now with the separate Azure subscription(Pay-As-You-Go). So not suitable for our needs. Further I found that it is a separate kind of Azure subscription called [Dev/Test](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devtest-lab/)

How can we get the 150 EUR per month credit from the Visual Studio Enterprise MSDN subscription as credit in our exsiting Azure subscription (Pay-As-You-Go)?

Comment: Dev/Test labs are a service on Azure and have nothing to do with subscriptions. MSDN subs being for dev/test purpose means the support is not as good, and certain VM sizes etc. might not be available. Otherwise performance is same, there is no difference.

Comment: `How can we get the 150 EUR per month credit from the Visual Studio Enterprise MSDN subscription as credit in our exsiting Azure subscription (Pay-As-You-Go)?` - You can't. Each Azure Subscription is the billing boundary and you can't port benefits of one Azure Subscription to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting the credit out of the MSDN offer, and transferring it to another subscription (basically the scenario you suggest) is not possible. These are two completely separate offers and cannot be combined in a sense.

Comment: Thanks to all for your immediate reply.